# Write a function to display the largest of three numbers. Anyone know where is wrong with my program?

Tags: c++, numbers, max, function-call, function-definition

(Largest of three numbers)
Write a function with the following header to display the largest of three numbers:

```
void displayLargest(double num1, double num2, double num3)
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter three numbers and invokes the function to display the largest of them.

The following is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

void displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3)
{  
    if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
        cout << num1;
    }
    else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
        cout << num2;
    }
    if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2){
        cout << num3;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double num1, num2, num3;
    cout << "Please enter 3 numbers:";
    cin >> num1, num2, num3;

    displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But, the system shows the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:28:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
     displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);
                     ^~~~~~
main.cpp:28:34: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
     displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);
                                  ^~~~~~
main.cpp:28:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
     displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);
                                               ^~~~~~
```

Comment: please review the chapter about calling functions in your c++ book.

Comment: hint: when you call eg `system` you also do not write `system(char [] "pause");`

Comment: What should happen when two numbers are equal?

Comment: `displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);` I guess the question you should be asking yourself is, why do I need to tell the compiler that `num1` is a double **again** when I already told it three lines earlier? Of course it should be `displayLargest(num1, num2, num3);`. And `cin >> num1, num2, num3;` should be `cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;`

Comment: The error is telling you what words are wrong and exactly where they are.

Comment: ah, I knew where I was wrong. thank you! !

Answer (score 1):

This

```
displayLargest (double num1, double num2, double num3);
```

is a syntactically invalid construction.

The function call will look like

```
displayLargest(num1, num2, num3);
```

If you are using the standard C function `system` then you need to include the header `<cstdlib>`.

Also the function itself is incorrect. It does not take into account that the user can enter three or two equal numbers.

The function can be defined in different ways.

Here are two examples of the function definition.

Either

```
void displayLargest( double num1, double num2, double num3 )
{
    if ( !( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ) )
    {
        std::cout << num1 << '\n';
    }
    else if ( !( num2 < num3 ) )
    {
        std::cout << num2 << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << num3 << '\n';
    }
}
```

or

```
void displayLargest( double num1, double num2, double num3 )
{
    double largest = num1;

    if ( largest < num2 )
    {
        largest = num2;
    }

    if ( largest < num3 )
    {
        largest = num3;
    }

    std::cout << largest << '\n';
}
```

If you are allowed to use standard algorithms then the function can be implemented using the algorithm `std::max`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void displayLargest( double num1, double num2, double num3 )
{
    std::cout << std::max( { num1, num2, num3 } ) << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    displayLargest( 1.2, 1.3, 1.1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your instruction!!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
displayLargest(double num1, double num2, double num3);
```

to:

```
displayLargest(num1, num2, num3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to read in three numbers in one line, simply extend the `cin` pipe to all three variables.

The issue you describe is a compilation error because you cannot re-declare the `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` variables. See the following code that corrects those issues.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void displayLargest(double num1, double num2, double num3)

{
  if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
    cout << num1;
  } else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3) {
    cout << num2;
  }
  if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2) {
    cout << num3;
  }

}

int main() {
  double num1, num2, num3;
  cout << "Please enter 3 numbers:";
  cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

  displayLargest(num1, num2, num3);
  return 0;
}
```

This is a sample input/output

```
./main
Please enter 3 numbers:1 2 3
3
```